# I want to solve the failure of build in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

while taking build some 3rd party packages like `flutter_form_builder,flutter_chips_input`also flutter `services` packages throws error,that leads to build failure ,I think that is package version crash problem.... but, i can't solve this problem....

How can i solve it?

below is error code.

thank you.

ERROR CODE

```
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-3.7.2/lib/src/fields/form_builder_range_slider.dart:21:9: Error: Type 'RangeSemanticFormatterCallback' not found.
  final RangeSemanticFormatterCallback semanticFormatterCallback;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.6.1/lib/src/chips_input.dart:62:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ChipsInputState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextInputClient.currentAutofillScope
 - TextInputClient.currentTextEditingValue
 - TextInputClient.performPrivateCommand
 - TextInputClient.showAutocorrectionPromptRect
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ChipsInputState<T> extends State<ChipsInput<T>>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:805:22: Context: 'TextInputClient.currentAutofillScope' is defined here.
  AutofillScope? get currentAutofillScope;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:793:25: Context: 'TextInputClient.currentTextEditingValue' is defined here.
  TextEditingValue? get currentTextEditingValue;
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:814:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.performPrivateCommand' is defined here.
  void performPrivateCommand(String action, Map<String, dynamic> data);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:823:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.showAutocorrectionPromptRect' is defined here.
  void showAutocorrectionPromptRect(int start, int end);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:273:8: Error: The method 'FlushbarRoute.install' has more required arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.
  void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
       ^
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:46:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('install').
  void install() {
       ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-3.7.2/lib/src/fields/form_builder_range_slider.dart:21:9: Error: 'RangeSemanticFormatterCallback' isn't a type.
  final RangeSemanticFormatterCallback semanticFormatterCallback;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:281:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.install(insertionPoint);
                 ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/gabriel/Git/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 900

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/gabriel/Git/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
```

############## Solution Things ###############

That situation is caused by selecting wrong package version....
so, i try to change version of "flutter_form_builder"!
and i solved this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `pubspec.lock`, remove `podfile.lock`, and run

`cd ios && pod repo update && cd .. && flutter clean && flutter pub get`

Answer (score 4):

This is due to incompatibilty of flutter_form_builder with your version of flutter. As advised on the [github](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder) page of flutter_form_builder, you need to choose the plugin according to your version of flutter.

From the github page:

> For Flutter 1.17.x, use version 3.12.x

> For Flutter 1.20.x, use version 3.13.x

> For Flutter 1.22.X, use version 3.14.x

You have to type the correct version number in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I appreciate your answer. For me using   flutter_form_builder: 3.14.0-alpha.1     worked awesome in Flutter 1.22.X. Have a good Day.